# Template virtual method for each type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

If I have a template as such:

```
template <typename ... TYPES>
class Visitor {
public:
    //virtual void visit(...) {}
};
```

Is there a way I can have C++ generate virtual methods "for each" type in the list?

For example, conceptually, I would like

```
class A;
class B;
class C;

class MyVisitor : public Visitor<A,B,C>;
```

To have the following virtual methods

```
virtual void visit(const A&) {}
virtual void visit(const B&) {}
virtual void visit(const C&) {}
```

Comment: `virtual void visit(const std::variant<const TYPES*...> &)` comes to mind. Then you can use `std::visit` within your `visit` to dispatch as you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add a base class template for `Visitor` and for each type in `TYPES` that defines a `visit` function for the type provided and then you would inherit from those base classes.  That would look like

```
template <typename T>
class VisitorBase
{
public:
    virtual void visit(const T&) { /* some code */ }
};

template <typename ... TYPES>
class Visitor : public VisitorBase<TYPES>... 
{
public:
    using VisitorBase<TYPES>::visit...; // import all visit functions into here
};
```

Comment: Nice, I never considered expanding a parameter pack in the base class list.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It's a handy technique.  Lets you build overload sets of functors which is really nice.